# How to design an Automatic QA System?

Tags: lucene, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, mahout

Will [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) be helpful for creating QA systems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have missunderstood how things work in here. We help people in solving problems in ideas they have, not create ideas or projects for people.

Comment: This is what I was talking about: "I want to know how to create QA systems like START(http://start.csail.mit.edu/),True knowledge(http://www.trueknowledge.com/) and what are all the steps involved in it."

Comment: Ok Fine. I'm curious to know about it and asked.

Comment: What about asking something like "I want to know how QA systems like START(start.csail.mit.edu/), True knowledge(trueknowledge.com) works". I think people will be more pleased to answer and you can get more feedback.

Answer (score 3):

How START works:

- http://groups.csail.mit.edu/infolab/publications/

How True Knowledge works:

- http://corporate.trueknowledge.com/technology/

How natural language QA systems work:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering#Question_answering_methods
- L. Hirschman , R. Gaizauskas, Natural language question answering: the view from here, Natural Language Engineering, v.7 n.4, p.275-300, December 2001. [PDF](http://www.loria.fr/~gardent/applicationsTAL/papers/jnle-qa.pdf)

Related questions (with answers recommending Lucene):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049058/natural-language-question-and-answer-system
- [IR and QA - Beginner Project Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196284/ir-and-qa-beginner-project-scope)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing information.

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan My [survey paper](https://goo.gl/ARvIdN) on QA systems may give you many more useful links for developing QA systems.